# Disable Jetpack Publicize for blog but keep for custom post type

Tags: facebook, plugin-jetpack

I have a WordPress site with a blog and also a custom post type (set up with Pods) called extra. I want the extra custom post type to be auto published to a Facebook page and the blog to just publish to the site.

I have set up Jetpack Publicize, and by default it publishes the blog (post) to Facebook but not a custom post type. By adding the snippet below in functions.php, Publicize publishes the custom post type to Facebook.

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init() {
    add_post_type_support( 'extra', 'publicize' );
}
```

How do I get publicize to not publish the blog is my question? I tried remove_post_type_support like so:

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'publicize' );
    add_post_type_support( 'extra', 'publicize' );
}
```

but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jeremy Herve:

"Posts support Publicize by default, so I'm afraid you won't be able to completely remove Publicize from the post screen.

I took note of your suggestion though, and we'll consider adding a filter to disable Publicize for posts in a future update."

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-publicize-to-facebook-for-blog?replies=3#post-6308156